# Response.Redirect Not Preserving Session Cookies

Tags: c#, .net, session, redirect, cookies

In my Global.asax.cs file on Application_AuthenicationRequest() I call

```
Response.Redirect("~/?someparameter=parameter", false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

In this same Global.asax.cs file in a method call SingleSignOn() I create and persist the session cookies in

```
Response.Cookie.Add(cookie);
```

In this same project I have a class called HomeController.cs that contains a method called Index() that contains the following line of code:

```
var queryString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["parameter"];
```

That is supposed to be called by the

```
Response.Redirect("~/?someparameter=parameter", false);
```

Located in the Global.asax.cs file. The problem appears to be that the session cookies are not preserved and therefore HomeController.Index() is not even being reached. When I run the code locally on my machine, everything works as I would expect. However, once deployed the call fails.

Comment: **1)** What's your goal and what do you want exactly to do? Are you looking for a security mechanism? A way for single sign on? or something else?

Comment: **2)** Next the question needs some clarifications. **•** The event is `AuthenticateRequest` and occurs when a security module has established the identity of the user. You said `Application_AuthenicationRequest`, is it a typo?  Also it doesn't seem to be a good idea to redirect in that method. **•** What's the content of `SingleSignOn` method and how do you create authentication cookie? And when/where do you call it? What mechanism for authentication do you use? ASP.NET Membership? ASP.NET Identity? **•** How do you made `/Home/Index` secure? Do you use `[Authorize]` Attribute?

Comment: Reza, Thanks for your response. Currently, the single-sign-on portion works without the new code that I have added which is supposed to do Response.Redirect("~/?someparameter=parameter", false). Essentially, the single-sign-on method I mentioned above already serves as security mechanism. You are correct, the event is AuthenticateRequest, however the method is implemented in the Global.asax.cs class as Application_AuthenticateRequest.

Comment: The content of the SingleSignOn method is that it creates the cookie using  System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(customObject, false). The cookie is then added to the Response.Cookies.Add(cookie). The SingleSignOn() method is then called from the Application_AuthenticationRequest() which then redirects to the /Home/Index if the user is validated within the SingleSignOn(). For security in the /Home/Index(HomeController.cs) we use custom annotation that extends the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: I've created SSO with Forms Authentication. Using the same domain for authentication cookies in your sites and also using the same machine keys in your sites are main key points. To make sure everything works, you should first use standard `Authorize` attribute, and then apply your customized attribute. Anyway in my implementation there was nothing related to `AuthenticateRequest`, I used `Logon` action for login and performed redirection there.

Comment: Any way, it would be better to share a larger and more clear picture of your logon and SSO process, then more effective helps can be shared. Or let me know if you let me know about the MVC version and your Authentication library (ASP.NET Membership/SimpleMembership/Identity) I can share something about SSO.

Comment: What's executing first, `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` or `Response.Cookie.Add(cookie);` ?

Comment: @Diego Response.Cookie.Add(cookie).

Comment: Are you redirecting to another site and then from that site back to homecontroller index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var queryString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["parameter"];
```

Should be

```
var queryString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["someparameter"];
```

If you want to get the actual value of someparameter

Your response needs to complete to the client in order for the cookie to be set.

By calling;

```
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

You're ending the response.

Read this;

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/network/cookies-csharp/

You can also only set cookies on the same domain, so if you are changing domains the browser won't set the cookie. I'm not sure why you're using a ~ in the response.

And further to this, some browsers won't set cookies on a redirect, so do some googling as to which ones accept it.

Hope this helps.